# Flexbox div width overflows on mobile

Tags: html, css, flexbox

This site (http://dev-500startups.pantheonsite.io/) I'm creating using Visual Composer on WordPress needs elements centered horizontally and vertically within a full-screen div.

So I used the following flexbox CSS code:

```
#home-header {
height: 100vh;
display: -webkit-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
-webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
-webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
        align-items: center;
}
```

And I applied that ID to the div container of the header. No other flexbox related properties are applied to divs and elements inside #home-header container.

It works well on desktop and tablets. But when I viewed using mobile in portrait mode (using both smartphones and simulator), that entire `#home-header` div width is always overflowing to the right side, which you can see here:

[image: overflows to the right]

This is using Chrome Inspector. Any other simulators give same results and same problem when I tested on phones too.

How can I get the elements to center vertically on the smaller screens like they do on larger ones?

Comment: too many unecessary files to go through  to easily narrow your trouble: 2 hints : **width set on somewhere** and not reset on media queries,  and eventually the use of word-break could be handy. for the centering, check for vertical margins values ...

Answer (score 0):

Replace css on and all works well https://yadi.sk/d/ZVvzgxD23ED7BE

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px)
responsive.min.css?ver=4.7.2:1
.header_inner_left, footer.uncover, header {
    position: absolute !important;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0!important;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Was set header 'position: relative'

Comment: Hey mate, thanks for reply! Unfortunately it doesn't work. And that CSS class is for header (which is the navigation area in this theme), no?

Comment: @SamuelFaith I attached a screenshot, which shows that the content is center-aligned https://yadi.sk/d/ZVvzgxD23ED7BE it work

Comment: Hey mate, I actually took the code (took out the responsive.min.css?ver=4.7.2:1 which I assume is from the browser debugger) and tried it out. :(